# How do i Loop this to send the Dm multiple times?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {
  let ids = ("385067115226595339")
  let dUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
  if (!dUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!")
  if (!ids.includes(message.author.id)) {
    return message.reply("Only the owner can do this!")
  };
  let dMessage = args.join(" ").slice(22);
  if(dMessage.length < 1) return message.reply('You must supply a message!')

  dUser.send(`${dMessage}`)

};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "=dm"
}
```

I want to loop this to send the DM multiple times, in the format =dm 10 @User Message

Comment: I don't see a loop in there.  What have you tried so far?  We can help you fix problems in your code, but SO isn't a code writing service.  Edit your question to include what you have tried and be clear about what problem you are having with it. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  const ids = ['385067115226595339']
  if (!ids.includes(message.author.id)) return message.reply('Only the owner can do this!')

  const user = message.mentions.users.first()
  const amount = Number(args[0])
  if (!args[2]) return message.reply('You must supply a message!')
  const dMessage = args.slice(2).join(' ')

  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) user.send(dMessage)
}
```

Assuming with the input `=dm 10 @username#0000 test message` `args` is `['10', '<@!userId>', 'test', 'message']`.